# how to create a print preview and report?

Tags: java, vb.net

Is there any tutorial that teach about how to create a print preview and report ?? I have only 2 weeks more to doing a project ?

thanks in advance

Makara

Comment: In Java or VB?   What are your other requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the crystal reports or the microsoft report viewer (rdlc)